# C++/CLI using XmlWriter with TcpClient not writing

Tags: c++-cli

I hope you'll forgive me if this is obvious; just starting out with c++/cli. I'm using some sample C# code to generate this but am using cli mode in a legacy c++ application so I'm having trouble in translation. Not easy finding samples on the web.

This is a snippet of code. An XDocument is passed into this code. I've checked it by writing to a file and the resulting xml file looks as it should (identical to the sample C# app). The tcpclient call seems to work, if I change the address, it throws an exception. I also see the connection established in a TCP Sniffer.

The request->WriteTo doesn't work - the sniffer shows no data written and the device doesn't respond.

Further, the XmlReader::Create call locks everything up.

Clearly, I've got something wrong in how I'm setting up the writer or the stream.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
            TcpClient ^ socket = gcnew TcpClient(address,port); // connect to device

            NetworkStream ^ stream;
            stream = socket->GetStream();   // get stream.

            XmlWriter ^writer = XmlWriter::Create(stream,xmlWrite);  // Create writer

            request->WriteTo(writer);   // Write XDocument to stream.

            XmlReader ^reader = XmlReader::Create(stream,xmlRead);
```

Comment: The TcpClient connects on the call above. As I pointed out, a TCP sniffer program shows it connected.

But I tried changing the code because I thought maybe you were on to something and created the socket without the address,port parameters and followed it with a socket->Connect(address,port) command.

Same behaviour.

This device I'm connecting to has very specific behaviour and I'm pretty sure it will close the stream. I'm not getting any response on the device and, in fact, the TCP sniffer shows no data sent from the WriteTo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good form or not but I found the answer so I'll post here in case anyone else has a similar problem:

After
    request->WriteTo(writer) 
I added
    writer->Flush().

Odd that the C# example I was working from didn't require this so if anyone has any insight into why the difference, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: That's not odd ;-) `XmlWriter` will buffer data for writing. Calling `Flush` tells it to send its buffer to the stream. I bet the C# code wrapped it in a `using` block (`Dispose` calls `Flush`), which could be translated to stack semantics in C++/CLI.